# Pitfalls of destructuring in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I was going through https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html#sec_pitfalls-destructuring. The second point at this link says that "**During destructuring, you can either declare variables or assign to them, but not both.**". However, I have seen many examples where declaration and assignment is taking place simultaneously during destructuring. One of them is mentioned below:

```
const [x, y, z] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
console.log(x, y, z); // prints a b c
```

In the example above, both declaration and assignment are happening. x, y, z are getting declared as constants and also getting a value assigned.

Could anybody help in understanding this statement? May be I am understanding it in a wrong manner.

Comment: The book is talking about the [assignment without declaration](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html#_where-can-destructuring-be-used)

Comment: @Bergi Is the example that I provided above in the question is of variable declaration and not assignment? And it would have been assignment's example when const keyword would not be there?

Comment: Technically it's a declaration with an initialiser. It's not an assignment *statement* for sure. Yes, without the `const` it would have been an assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think meaning here is that if you have already defined variables you can't perform this:

```
let a, b;
const [a, b, c] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to word this would be "**When destructuring, you can either declare and assign all variables or only assign to existing variables**"

For example, this would not work because `x` is already defined, but then you'd have to use another line to only define `y` and `z`:

```
let x = null
let [x, y, z] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

you are destructuring an array by assigning a pattern to it, not by declaring constants. Although the latter occurred due to the former.

Check the last note of 10.2 in that link. Bergi wrote it already